# Store info in a column as JSON

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I'm learning SQL Server 2016, I learned how to extract JSON from tables.

Now I need to store JSON in a column. My JSON was:

```json
{"endereco":"R. Nome da Rua, 000", "cep":"00000-000"}
```

I`m using *nvarchar* as the column type, but when I store it using:

```
UPDATE test2 SET endereco = '{"endereco":"R. Nome da Rua, 000", "cep":"00000-000"}'
```

When I do a select, it shows like this:

```json
{\"endereço\":\"R. Nome da Rua, 000\", cep:\"00000-000\"}
```

But I was expecting this:

```json
{"endereco":"R. Nome da Rua, 000", "cep":"00000-000"}
```

What was I supposed to do?

My test table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teste2]
(
  [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [descricao] [varchar](200)  NULL,
  [endereco] [nvarchar](MAX)  NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

```
SELECT
    descricao [nome],
    JSON_QUERY(endereco) [endereco]
FROM teste2
WHERE id=2
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('clientes')
```

The "magic" was performed by `JSON_QUERY (expression, path )` as documented here:

[JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921884.aspx)

See also:

[Frequently Asked Questions about JSON in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt631706.aspx)